# Disqus' embed.js not firing the afterRender

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, disqus

First off, let me start by saying that I'm using Disqus (embed.js iframe) on a single-page-application. What I want to achieve is only show a couple of comments with a button called "Show more" (it's obvious what happens when a user clicks it).

How I did that was I put the disqus iframe inside a container for which I set a fixed height and a hidden overflow and a button under it. When the user clicks the button, I set the height to `auto`.

All works nicely, except that I needed the button to only be visible after the comments are loaded (which makes sense - the user doesn't want to see "Show more comments" even before they're loaded). So i tried adding an `afterRender` function but it just doesn't work.

**TLDR**

Disqus does not fire the `afterRender` event.

[Check out my jsbin](https://jsbin.com/lipudu/edit?html,css,js,console,output).

Comment: I don’t find any mention of a `afterRender` callback that disqus is supposed to fire. Can you link to the relevant parts of the documentation? Also, please show us some code.

Comment: The asker has provided a jsbin clearly showing the problem

Comment: I linked my jsbin (as far as code is concerned).  And the `afterRender` event I got by googling and by looking in the `embed.js`. Here is one link: https://gist.github.com/opi/2234861

Comment: You can also inspect the contents of this.callbacks and clearly see the afterRender.

Comment: Your button shows if you change to `this.callbacks.onReady`